# Where does the firebase listeners listen to RAM or disk?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the following code:-

```
 String FirebaseRefer = Constants.Client + "/" + Constants.firebaseProjects + "/" + Constants.name + "/xyz";
DatabaseReference agendaRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseRefer);
agendaRef.keepSynced(true);    

agendaRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot) {
```

where does the firebase listener listen to? Is it the firebase data in the RAM or to that in the disk?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Database client keeps a copy of all data that you're listening to in memory of your app. Once you remove the last listener for a location, the data is removed from memory. Since you call `agendaRef.keepSynced(true)`, this means that all data at `agendaRef` is kept in memory, and kept up to date.

If you [enable persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-offline-behavior) the client will also persist active and recent data to disk.

Comment: kept up to date means what?

Comment: And if we dont enable persistence, then does that mean that everytime the data needs to be fetched from remote firebase? In general is the data fetched from local firebase in the disk or remote firebase? If always from remote firebase what is the use of storing it to disk?

Comment: When you have an active listener (or have called `keepSynced(true)` on a node) the Firebase client gets notified of changes to the data on the server and updates its cache (and notifies its listeners) when the data changes. That's what I mean by "kept up to date".

Comment: To learn more about what happens on the wire, I highly recommend that you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and study logcat.

Answer (score 0):

When we are talking about listeners, actually we are talking about the number of read/writes operations that you do in a certain time, the number of read/writes you do per second because every `disk` has a maximum number of I/O (input/output operations) per second. When it comes to Firebase, the Firebase database is not different. So, to answer your question, Firebase listeners `listen on the disk`.

One thing to rememebr, beeing on shared infrastructure, the number of `IOPS` is not guaranteed.